# How many lines of code are in my Stata do-file, excluding comments?

Tags: comments, stata

Is there a fast way to see how many lines of code are in my Stata do-file (.do), not counting the comments? I could make a new version and delete all the comments out by hand, but that's too tedious for what I need.

My intent is to compare the lengths of an old version vs. a new version of the do file. I want to see whether I have made the code more efficient. However, I have some large commented sections of non-vital code in the files that I don't need to count.

A closely related question: is there a way to quickly see a total of all lines of code in a project (rather than just the do-file) - either including or excluding comments? Thank you.

Comment: It's worth thinking about how long the code takes to run, rather than the number of lines, as an alternative, and often quite more useful, measure of efficiency. See `help timer` for more information.

Comment: Length of code has nothing much to do with efficiency. How best to count comment lines depends partly on how you indicated comments. One technique is to read in your file as data -- one string variable -- and then count how many observations are of whatever kind.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the timer - interesting. An odd thing about my case is that I'm running the new do file with far more observations than I used to do with the old file. It takes noticeably longer to run, so I know it's going to be less efficient in that sense. I have changed several variable names, so I can't easily run the old code with the new data, either. Sounds like there isn't a quick line-counting feature in Stata. Thanks for the input!